# Passing variables to MX Notify via Safecracker

Tags: safecracker

I have a safecracker form for visitors to submit events. I'm trying to capture their email address to use with MX notify ({author_email}) . Is this even possible?

```
<div id="calendar_saef_edit">
   {exp:safecracker 
   channel="calendar_events" 
   return="/events/add-event/success"
   logged_out_member_id="2"
   error_handling="inline"
   status="Pending"
   }

     {if error}
                <p class="error">{error}</p>
        {/if}

   <p><strong><label>Your Full Name:</label></strong><br />
   <input type="text" name="full_name" /></p>
    <p><strong><label>Your Email Address:</label></strong><br />
   <input type="text" name="event_email_address" /></p>
     <p><strong><label>Business/Organization Name:</label></strong><br />
   <input type="text" name="business_name" /></p>
   <p><strong><label>Event Title:</label></strong><br />
   <input type="text" name="title" /></p>
   {exp:calendar:date_widget event_id="{segment_5}"}
    <p><span class="label label-info">Hint:</span> If an event is multiple days, change the "repeat" drop-down menu to "Select Dates". Then, click each day that the event is happening. Don't create an event for every single day. </p>



      <label>Event Photo:</label>
      {field:event_photo}


   <p><strong><label>Event Summary:</label></strong><br />
  {field:event_summary}
   <p><strong><label>Event Location:</label></strong><br />
   <input type="text" name="event_location" value="{event_location}" /></p>
   <input type="hidden" id="status" name="status" value="Pending">
    <input type="hidden" id="mbr_email" name="mbr_email" value="{event_email_address}">
    <input type="hidden" id="author_email" name="author_email" value="{event_email_address}">
   <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Event" class="btn btn-success" /></p>
   {/exp:safecracker}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

nope,  it is not possible. Only if modify ext. and add option to parsing custom fields for mbr_email

Answer (score 1):

While not a free solution, it's possible to do this with Postmaster. Postmaster is highly extendible and provides a rich full-featured API for you to send email for just about anything. Templates can be highly dynamic, and if the desired functionality doesn't exist, just use the API to create exactly what you need.

https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster

Comment: Postmaster is a great solution for this, I'm using it to do pretty much the same thing!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's totally possible simply use {author_email} in the email "to" field from the Modules/Extention/Settings section of the plugin.

1. Navigate to the Add-ons/extentions/MX Notify Control-> click on settings
2. "To Email" add {author_email} *(or what ever the name of the input field used in your safe cracker form)*

That's it !

Comment: Hello, thanks for contributing to the site, could you come back and complete this answer? It looks to me like you meant to add something more under (1) above, but perhaps forgot?

Comment: I really wish that this could work, but it doesn't... It causes a PHP error upon sending the corresponding Safecracker form: 'Message: mail(): SMTP server response: 550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable or not local'